# Gradients of marginal likelihood of Gaussian Process with squared exponential covariance, for learning hyper-parameters

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process

The derivation of gradient of the marginal likelihood is given in [this pdf, equation 5.9](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW5.pdf). But the gradient for the most commonly used covariance function, squared exponential covariance, is not explicitly given. (or the second order derivative)

I am implementing the Rprop algorithm in [this pdf, section 2](http://ml.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/_media/publications/blumesann2013.pdf) for learning hyper-parameters sigma (signal variance) and h (length). Alas, my implementation is not working well. I have derived the gradients and I suspect I did something wrong.

(Squared exponential covariance function: $k(x,x')=\sigma \exp\left(\frac{||x-x'||^2}{2h^2}\right)$

Can someone point me to a good tutorial / article that explicitly give the expressions for the hyper parameter gradients?

Comment: Can you add some of the necessary context into the question? People may not want to read these pdfs just so they can understand & answer this question. Also, the links may go dead over time.

Comment: Okay. I added a reference to the section and equation number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1072701/84783) which will show you and explain how it is implemented in most libraries.